# Is InheritedWidget should always need to be a child of StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, provider, inherited-widget

**Things that I know about InheritedWidget?**

InheritedWidgets are not rebuilts instead we have to create a new InheritedWidget with a new value.
Then inside the updateShouldNotify() method will compare its old and current object and return true or false.

if updateShouldNotify() returns **true** -> then dependent contexts get rebuild.

if updateShouldNotify() returns **false** -> then dependent contexts doesn't rebuild.

```
@override
bool updateShouldNotify(_InheritedCount old) {
  return old.state != state;
}
```

So every time when we creating a new instance of the previous InheritedWidget will call that updateShouldNotify() method and decided to rebuilt their dependents or not.

**What I want to know about InheritedWidget ?** (things that I confused)

1. Does every InheritedWidget need to be wrap with StatefulWidget to creates its new instance of that InheritedWidget ?
2. Does ChangeNotifierProvider wrap its InheritedWidget (or InheritedProvider) in a StatefulWidget to recreate new InheritedWidget,  when ChangeNotifier object sends change notification to its ChangeNotifierProvider() ?

*(be kind about how I handle English language)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, most of the time you will need to wrap an `InheritedWidget` in a `StatefulWidget` to cause rebuilds.

There's an exception when using `InheritedNotifier` instead of `InheritedWidget`, but that's fairly rare.

> Does ChangeNotifierProvider wrap its InheritedWidget (or InheritedProvider) in a StatefulWidget to recreate new InheritedWidget, when ChangeNotifier object sends change notification to its ChangeNotifierProvider() ?

That's similar to what Provider does, yes.

It doesn't use this exact combination though. Instead Provider implemented a new kind of InheritedWidget: `InheritedProvider`.

This `InheritedProvider` is both a `StatefulWidget` and an `InheritedWidget` in a single widget. It's an `InheritedWidget` with a `setState` / `dispose`